# PureFTPd and symlinks

Tags: centos, security, ftp

I'm running **Pure-FTPD** on **centos 5** with **cPanel** installed.

When somebody upload a symlink file called 1.txt and it's a **symlink** to **/partition** for example, He can browse all **/partition** contents from this symlink through Pure-FTPD and it's a dangerous security problem.

How can i solve this security issue and disable symlinks browing on FTP .?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set up chroot feature in 'pureftpd' configuration. Once your users will be 'chrooted', they will not be able to go outside from their home directories.

Additional info:

http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README

http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ

Comment: `ChrootEveryone` directive is set to `yes` in my prue-ftpd.conf

Comment: @LinuxIntel Probably, your `pureftpd` instance has been built with `virtualchroot` option: " --with-virtualchroot: usually, when a user is chrooted (-A and -a options), it's impossible to go out of his home directory. Enabling that feature makes it possible: symbolic links are always followed, even if they are pointing to directories not located in the user's home directory. This is very useful for having shared directories (for instance, have a symbolic link to /var/incoming in every home directory). This feature isn't enabled by default."

Comment: `pure-ftpd` is installed by default on `cPanel`, And i can not find the complie parameters. How can i know `virtualchroot` is disabled or enabled .?

Comment: @LinuxIntel you can check the options which it has been built with downloading according SRPM and looking through the spec.

Comment: unfortunately i can not find the compile parameters, But i add this `VIRTUALCHROOT false` into my `pure-ftpd.com` and the symlinks still working.

Comment: @LinuxIntel It's a global feature, it cannot be disabled in config if it's enabled during build. If you don't need this functionality, you have to rebuild `pure-ftpd` with your options set. That's simple. First, you should find out where the binary package came from (epel, cpanel private repo, etc.: `rpm -qi pure-ftpd`). Then, you download SRPM from the same source, install it, edit `pure-ftpd.spec` file (in `/usr/src/redhat/SPECS` by default) - remove `--with-virtualchroot` line only, and build binary packages: `rpmbuild -bb pure-ftpd.spec`.) Certainly, you'll need install some deps first.